# Using withColumn, assign value to only the last row in a group in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with groups that can be ordered by time.

```
Group   | Time | Food
-------------------------
Fruits  | 1    | Apples
Fruits  | 3    | Ketchup
Fruits  | 5    | Bananas
Veggies | 2    | Broccoli
Veggies | 4    | Peas
Veggies | 8    | Carrots
```

As part of a more complicated `when().otherwise()` clause inside of `withColumn()` I need to assign a value into that new column for the last row of each group. I suspect I should use row number so I have something like this:

```
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Group").orderBy("Time")

my_table \
.withColumn("group_row", F.row_number().over(windowSpec)) \
.withColumn("is_window_last", 
            F.when(F.max("group_row").over(windowSpec) == F.col("group_row"), "Last")
             .otherwise("Not Last")) \
.show()
```

I would expect the result to be

```
Group   | Time | Food.    | group_row | is_window_last
-------------------------------------------
Fruits  | 1    | Apples   | 1         | Not Last
Fruits  | 3    | Ketchup  | 2         | Not Last
Fruits  | 5    | Bananas  | 3         | Last
Veggies | 2    | Broccoli | 1         | Not Last
Veggies | 4    | Peas     | 2         | Not Last
Veggies | 8    | Carrots  | 3         | Last
```

But instead I get

```
Group   | Time | Food.    | group_row | is_window_last
-------------------------------------------
Fruits  | 1    | Apples   | 1         | Last
Fruits  | 3    | Ketchup  | 2         | Last
Fruits  | 5    | Bananas  | 3         | Last
Veggies | 2    | Broccoli | 1         | Last
Veggies | 4    | Peas     | 2         | Last
Veggies | 8    | Carrots  | 3         | Last
```

I've tried

```
my_table \
.withColumn("group_row", F.row_number().over(windowSpec)) \
.withColumn("is_window_last", 
            F.when(F.max("group_row").over(windowSpec) == F.col("group_row").over(windowSpec), "Last")
             .otherwise("Not Last")) \
.show()
```

and

```
my_table \
.withColumn("group_row", F.row_number().over(windowSpec)) \
.withColumn("is_window_last", 
            F.when((F.max("group_row") == F.col("group_row")).over(windowSpec), "Last")
             .otherwise("Not Last")) \
.show()
```

but neither did what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use the **same** `windowSpec` on both window function

```py
windowSpec = W.partitionBy("g").orderBy("t")

(df
    .withColumn('group_row', F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy('g').orderBy('t')))
    .withColumn('max_group', F.max('group_row').over(W.partitionBy('g'))) # DON'T order by 'time' here
    .withColumn('is_window_last', F
        .when(F.col('max_group') == F.col('group_row'), 'Last')
        .otherwise('Not Last')
    )
    .show()
)

+-------+---+--------+---------+---------+--------------+
|      g|  t|       f|group_row|max_group|is_window_last|
+-------+---+--------+---------+---------+--------------+
| Fruits|  1|  Apples|        1|        3|      Not Last|
| Fruits|  3| Ketchup|        2|        3|      Not Last|
| Fruits|  5| Bananas|        3|        3|          Last|
|Veggies|  2|Broccoli|        1|        3|      Not Last|
|Veggies|  4|    Peas|        2|        3|      Not Last|
|Veggies|  8| Carrots|        3|        3|          Last|
+-------+---+--------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

This `F.max("group_row").over(windowSpec)` will calculate max of `group_row` **per row**. If you remove `orderBy(time)` on that window function, you will get max of `group_row` **per group**

Answer (score 0):

I would use Last, row number will incur more compute effort. You will be required to compute max row number to achieve your objective.

```
w=Window.partitionBy('Group').orderBy('Time').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)


df.withColumn('c',last('Food').over(w)).withColumn('c', when(col('Food')==col('c'),'Last').otherwise('Not Last')).show()

+-------+----+--------+--------+
|  Group|Time|    Food|       c|
+-------+----+--------+--------+
| Fruits|   1|  Apples|Not Last|
| Fruits|   3| Ketchup|Not Last|
| Fruits|   5| Bananas|    Last|
|Veggies|   2|Broccoli|Not Last|
|Veggies|   4|    Peas|Not Last|
|Veggies|   8| Carrots|    Last|
+-------+----+--------+--------+
```